# Get all Vector2 Points Within Radius

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry

I am looking for a formula that will give me all of the `Vector2 Points` within a certain radius given the center.

Essentially what I am trying to do is change the color of each pixel in a  256 x 256 texture that is within a certain radius from a specific pixel (Using the Unity3d Game Engine). Programming Language doesn't really matter, as I can probably convert it to something I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `cx` and `cy` be center x and center y, and `r` be the radius.

```
r2 = r * r;
for each dy = 0 ... r
    dx = 0
    while (dx*dx + dy*dy <= r2)
        within(cx+dx, cy+dy)
        within(cx-dx, cy+dy)
        within(cx+dx, cy-dy)
        within(cx-dx, cy-dy)
        dx++
```

An optimization would be, not to reset `dx` to 0 in each iteration, but to some closer value right away.